# Trouble with / vs ./ vs ../ and absolute and relative paths

Tags: php

I have many PHP files in

```
/
/client/
/user/
/config/
etc...
```

I want all my files to include `/user/codestart.php`.  (Lots of functions etc)

Therefore:

- All files in `/` have `include("./user/codestart.php");`
- All files in `/user/` have `include("codestart.php");`
- All files in `/client/` have `include("../user/codestart.php");`

The problem is that `/user/codestart.php` has `include("../config/config.php");`  (The MySQL ID and password)

When a file in `/` runs, such as `/index.php`, it includes `./user/codestart.php`. 
Then `/user/codestart.php` includes `../config/config.php`, but it cannot see it, because it thinks it is calling it from `/`, instead of from `/user/`.

If I change
`include("../config/config.php")` to be
`include("./config/config.php")`
that fixes it for `/` files, but breaks it for`/user/` and`/client/` files.

Bottom line is that when one PHP file includes another file, PHP thinks it is operating from the location of the original file, not the calling file.

I need to use relative paths, not absolute paths.  Absolute paths will not work in my situation.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Q: "Any way to solve this?" A: Use absolute paths. Q: "I don't want to use absolute paths." A: Oh.

Comment: I see you edited to add "Absolute paths will not work in my situation" - could you explain that? See, the trouble is that absolute paths work in ALL situations - the statement is nonsensical. Could you perhaps explain what this situation is that you feel excludes the most rational solution to the problem? Please elaborate - I'd like to help but this just does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with this is this:

- Have a central configuration file (e.g. `/myproject/config/bootstrap.php`
- In that configuration file, define a global root for your application. E.g.

  ```
  define("APP_ROOT", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/.."));
  ```
- Include that configuration file in every PHP file. E.g.

  ```
  include("../config/bootstrap.php");
  ```
- Whenever you reference some other file, use

  ```
  include APP_ROOT."/includes/somefile.php";
  ```

Voilá - you have a fixed point in space (`APP_ROOT`) and can reference everything relative to that, no matter which directory you are in.

Comment: yes, and use any other ways to include this configuration from all files?

Comment: @RiaD you have to specify the full relative path to the configuration file (unless you want to set a global `include_path` or something). It means that you have to change the relative path if you move the file - an acceptable tradeoff IMO, because that isn't going to happen that often.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it this way I suggest you make a seperate file for all your includes which is in a fixed dir, the root for example.

Then you reliably include all the files from there using

```
include __DIR__.'path/relative/from/includefile.php'
```

If your php verion is lower than 5.3 you should use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__` as mentioned by **RiaD**

You might like [this php.net page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: requires PHP 5.3 use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead in PHP 5.2 or older

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative paths in conjuntion with dirname(`__FILE__`)

So in your codestart file write:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

use absolute paths. to get path to your root directory use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, ex.

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/user/codestart.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/config.php';
```

It save you from absolute paths' problems.

Comment: Relying on `DOCUMENT_ROOT` has the shortcoming that you can place your application only in the document root and not a subdirectory. It's fine in many scenarios but I never use it for that reason

Comment: @Pekka: you may use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../.....' too if you know relative position from document_root to your real root

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path that PHP uses to look for files, so that it contains all your folders.  In `index.php`:

```
$folders = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array('user', 'config'));
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.$folders);
```

Then you can just do:

```
include("codestart.php");
```

and:

```
include("config.php");
```

This will work for `index.php` and all files that `index.php` includes.